# does this limit exist ? if yes how to compute it?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

How to find this limit (if it exists) : $\lim_{z \to 0} \left({\dfrac{\sin(z)}{z}}\right)^{\frac{1}{z^2}}$ 
where $z$ is a complex number.

Comment: Try finding it. You might as well able to do that.

Comment: I did try finding it but found that it equals to one.
I used this identity : x^a = e^(a*ln(x))
then did a taylor expansion for ln(sin(z)/z) simplified and found one
is that correct ?

Comment: From now onward please try to write a little bit of what you did with the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\left({\dfrac{\sin z}{z}}\right)^{\frac{1}{z^2}}$ then $\ln y=\dfrac{\ln\sin z-\ln z}{z^2}$ two times L'Hospital rule shows
$$\lim_{z \to 0} \ln y=\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{-\sin z}{4\sin z+2z\cos z}=-\frac16$$
so $\lim_{z \to 0} y=e^{-\frac16}$

Answer (score 1):

For small $z$, $\frac{\sin z}{z}\approx 1-\frac{z^2}{6}\approx \exp -\frac{z^2}{6}$ so the limit is $\exp -\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: how can 1 be close to exp ?

Comment: $1+x\approx e^x$ for small $x$.

Comment: ah it's exp(-z^2/6) thought it was exp(1) - z^2/6
was confused for a moment.

thank you for shedding light.

Answer (score 1):

Write it as $$(1+z^2f(z))^{\frac{1}{z^2}}$$

where $$f(z)=\frac{\sin z-z}{z^3}$$

Thus you get the limit $$e^{-\frac{1}{6}}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Rewrite the limit as
$$\lim_{z \to 0} \left({\dfrac{\sin z}{z}}\right)^{\frac{1}{z^2}} \stackrel{!}{=} \exp \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{1}{z^2}\ln \left(\frac{\sin z}{z} \right)$$
and apply L'Hospital.